# Value mismatch using copy data activity in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using copy data activity to load an xlsx file to a sql server table(columns with nvarchar datatype).

I find that for some random values there is a difference in the value for 14th decimal place(I have the value upto 14 decimal places and the last digit varies)
For example: xlsx source has 1.12345678901234 and sink has 1.12345678901235

This is not happening for all values but some, however consistently happening for the same value in any number of reloads.

I tried to convert to csv file using copy data activity, but still with the same output(1.12345678901235).

Could anyone advise on why its the case and if there are any ways to overcome it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its a limitation (or feature) in Copy activity , it **Rounds up** the decimals, what i can recommend to you is converting your decimals into Strings and then copy your data to SQl after coping your data just re-convert it into decimal again (use a dummy column or so ).

Comment: Hi Sally, thanks for your response, but there is no digit after this for it to round up(unless there is something that excel hides from us) and its not happening for all the values with the same 14 decimals. Its just for some but consistently always for the same set of values. That makes it strange. And i am not converting, I am loading values from xlsx to either a column in DB with nvarchar or just into a csv file, neither is solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this and it is working fine for me with the below sample excel data.

[image]

Output **SQL table** which had **nvarchar columns** in sink after Copy activity.

[image]

I am getting the same data even after copying from excel to a csv file in blob using ADF.

What I can suggest you is rather than using the excel file try to save it as csv file in the Excel itself and copy it to SQL table. This may work.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thanks for your response. As I mentioned, it is not happening for all the values but only for some values in the dataset. So we are unable to replicate with some random input values. And I did try to save it as csv but still the same issue. I think the issue is due to some floating point accuracy errors.